# How to make requests not to do something in reported speech?

Tags: grammar, phrase-requests

Specifically in the sentence: “A guide asked us not to touch the exhibits during the excursion”.

Do we use 〜て／でください as if we are saying “don’t touch this” or do we simply put a negative form and then と + some introductory verb?

Like:

> 案内者は見学の時に陳列品を手で持たないと... etc.

And what verb should we use to say “she asked”? I guess neither 聞く nor 頼む will be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If the guide is explaining several things, I would say:
作品に手を触れないようにと案内者は説明しました。

But if the guide is scolding you for having touched the exhibits, I would say:
作品に手を触れないようにと案内者に注意されました。

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one more question: is it mandatory to put the particle と after ように in this situation?